# Trouble Rendering a Sphere in WebGL and Typescript

Tags: webgl, typescript

Ive ported over some c code that renders a sphere in opengl for a webgl/typescript project I'm working on, however its not rendering correctly. I've compared the indices and vertices between the c and ts versions and they appear to match. The code is as follows:

```
constructor(ctx: WebGLRenderingContext, stacks:number, 
                slices:number, scale: number){
    var vertices: number[] = [];
    var normals: number[] = [];
    var indices: number[] = [];

    var ii: number;
    var jj: number;
    var v: number;
    var u: number;

    normals.push(0, 0, 1);
    vertices.push(0, 0, scale);

    for (ii = 0; ii < slices; ++ii) {
        indices.push(0);
        indices.push(ii + 1);
    }
    indices.push(0);
    indices.push(1);

    for (ii = 1; ii < stacks; ++ii) {
        v = ii / stacks;
        for (jj = 0; jj < slices; ++jj) {
            u = jj / slices;
            normals.push.apply(normals, this.shapeNormal(u, v));
            vertices.push.apply(vertices, this.shapeVertex(scale, u, v));

            indices.push((ii - 1) * slices + (jj + 1));
            var index_offset: number = ((ii + 1) === stacks) ? 0 : jj;
            var second: number = ii * slices + (index_offset + 1);
            //console.log("Offset: " + String(index_offset) + " Value: " + String(second));
            indices.push(second);
        }
        indices.push((ii - 1) * slices + 1);
        indices.push(ii * slices + 1);
    }

    normals.push(0, 0, -1);
    vertices.push(0, 0, -scale);

    //console.log("Theoretical vertices: " + String(3 * (2 + slices * (stacks - 1))));

    //initialise vbos
    console.log("Vertices: " + String(vertices.length / 3));
    for(var l = 0; l < vertices.length; l += 3)
        console.log(vertices[l].toFixed(6) + " " + vertices[l+1].toFixed(6) + " " + vertices[l+2].toFixed(6));
    this.vertices = new VertexBufferObject(ctx, 3, vertices.length / 3);
    //console.log("Normals: " + String(normals.length));
    this.normals = new VertexBufferObject(ctx, 3, normals.length / 3);
    console.log("Indices: " + String(indices.length) + " " + indices.toString());
    this.indices = new VertexBufferObject(ctx, 1, indices.length);

    //populate vbo
    ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
    ctx.bindBuffer(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertices.buffer);
    ctx.bufferData(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), ctx.STATIC_DRAW);

    ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(1);
    ctx.bindBuffer(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normals.buffer); 
    ctx.bufferData(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(normals), ctx.STATIC_DRAW);

    ctx.bindBuffer(ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indices.buffer);
    ctx.bufferData(ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), 
                        ctx.STATIC_DRAW);

    ctx.bindBuffer(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
    ctx.bindBuffer(ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

    ctx.disableVertexAttribArray(0);
    ctx.disableVertexAttribArray(1);

    this.ctx = ctx;
}

private shapeVertex(r: number, u: number, v: number): number[] {
    /* Use maths rather than physics spherical coordinate convention */
    var theta: number = u * 2.0 * Math.PI;
    var phi: number = v * Math.PI;

    var vert: number[] = [
        r * Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(phi),
        r * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi),
        r * Math.cos(phi)
    ];

    return vert;
}

private shapeNormal(u: number, v: number): number[] {
    /* Use maths rather than physics spherical coordinate convention */
    var theta: number = u * 2.0 * Math.PI;
    var phi: number = v * Math.PI;

    var norm: number[] = [
        Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(phi),
        Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi),
        Math.cos(phi)
    ];

    var mag: number = Math.sqrt(norm[0] * norm[0] + norm[1] * norm[1] + norm[2] * norm[2]);

    norm[0] /= mag;
    norm[1] /= mag;
    norm[2] /= mag;

    return norm;
}

public draw(shaderProgram: ShaderProgram): void {
    //bind and draw vbo's
    this.ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
    this.ctx.bindBuffer(this.ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertices.buffer);
    this.ctx.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.attributes.position, 
                        this.vertices.itemSize, this.ctx.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    this.ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(1);
    this.ctx.bindBuffer(this.ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normals.buffer);
    this.ctx.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.attributes.normal, 
                        this.normals.itemSize, this.ctx.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    this.ctx.bindBuffer(this.ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indices.buffer);
    this.ctx.drawElements(this.ctx.TRIANGLES, this.indices.numItems, 
                        this.ctx.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    this.ctx.bindBuffer(this.ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
    this.ctx.bindBuffer(this.ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

    this.ctx.disableVertexAttribArray(0);
    this.ctx.disableVertexAttribArray(1);
}
```

and a screenshot of the result:

[Broken Sphere](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/117543167/Capture.PNG)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As TypeScript is just a supersed of Javascript, your problem is probably related to how Javascript handle your code computations.

I'm not sure about your code as you didn't provide the original source.
Assuming your code is correct, you may encounter a [floating point approximation error](http://blog.greweb.fr/2013/01/be-careful-with-js-numbers/).